# Pass the dropdown selected value to NodeJS for querying database

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have created one dropdown that passes data to NodeJS through axios post i can see that in console log of nodejs Post but cant able to use the value outside  the post function

i want to use the value to querying the database

my nodejs code:

```
  app.post('/getmodel', (req, res) => {
      var model = req.body.model;
    
    console.log(model);
    //It shows model value here but can't able to use outside       
    
  });


app.get('/model', (req,res)=>{
    let model = req.body.model;
 let sql ="select * from new_schema.model_list,new_schema.images where model_name=  " + mysql.escape(model)
 db.query(sql,model, (err,results) =>{
        if(err){
            throw err
        }
         console.log(results)
        res.send(results);
    })
})
```

my react code works fine as i can able to see the selected value in nodejs console below

[image]

these are the selected value from my dropdown that shows in my nodejs console. but in cant use it by req.body like that please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
app.post('/getmodel', (req, res) => {
    var model = req.body.model;

    console.log(model);
    //It shows model value here and you can able to use in the query

    let sql = "select * from new_schema.model_list,new_schema.images where model_name=  " + mysql.escape(model)
    db.query(sql, model, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        console.log(results)
        res.send(results);
    })

});
```

Comment: bro this works great i want to show the result in json output in browser. it only show in console right now . can you guide me how to show output in browser as json?

Comment: Could you post your react code where you call Axios post ? There you should get the json reponse

Comment: thanks bro it works well   handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      axios.post('http://localhost:5000/getmodel', {
        model: this.state.model,
      })
       .then((res) => {
        // Res.data is the response from your server
        console.log(res.data);
      });
    }

Comment: can i get your mail id or twitter id. i'm new to full stack development bro i need people who guide me to become one. i believe you can help me to improve too can you give me one of your social media id?